# adding two objects to a hashMap?

Tags: java

Have I correctly added an element to a hashTable?

```
Flows flows = new Flows(sIP,dIP);
FlowStatics flowStatics = new FlowStatics(packetLength,timeArrival);

HashMap myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();
myHashMap.put(flows, flowStatics);
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable, because whether it is "the right way" depends entirely on what the purpose of your program is. One thing to note: The object that you use as the key must implement `hashCode()` and `equals()` correctly.

Comment: @Red Lion: Yes, that's right (with the caveats that @Jesper mentioned). Remember though that you're not just "adding two objects", you're creating a mapping between one (`flows`) and another (`flowStatics`), such that you can later look up `flowStatics` using `flows` as a key.

Comment: post your Flows class and we can tell you if it is acceptable for use as a HashMap key

Comment: @Jesper: I need to capture a packet, looked for its srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol. if there already exists such a packet then i look for some statics about that packet and extract them such as its payload length.
if there is not such packet i add it first and then look for its statics.
this makes up a flow which is a set of packets all with the same source and destination address. i desire to keep all packet's statics belong to a flow in my case.

Comment: @David: you are totally right. thanks

Comment: @Steve: I pated my code down here. i would be pleased if you can have a look a it.

Comment: C'mon guys, don't close this just because he used "is it the right way?". Clearly he means: "have I done this correctly?"

Comment: @Steve I voted to close this because there's no way to tell if he did this correctly! It depends on what he means with that code, and what the application is supposed to do.

Comment: @David: as my key is an object how can i do that mapping? i wanted to print my hashMap by iterating over keys, but it is impossible. can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid compiler warnings, code it like this:

```
HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics> myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();
myHashMap.put(flows, flowStatics);
```

If you don't parametrize the myHashMap variable, then you can't add in the second line without getting warnings.

---

Here is working example on how to 'print' some hashmap statistics:

```
HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics> myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  // OP commented that the map is populated in a loop
  myHashMap.put(createNewFlow(), createNewFlowStatistics());  // populate map
}
System.out.printf("Number of items in Map: %s%n", myHashMap.keyset().size());
```

(OP asked for adivice in a comment to another answer)

Answer (score 3):

The code looks ok.

However you should make sure that `Flows` override `equals` and `hashCode`

Comment: `hashCode`, not `hashcode`. Case is important!

Answer (score 3):

Replace this line

```
HashMap myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();
```

with this one

```
Map<Flows, FlowStatics> myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change `HashMap myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();`
to `HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics> myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();` but the addig is completly ok.

Comment: but i can not print the map out.

Comment: @Red Lion - What kind of print result do you expect?

Comment: at least to check number of keysets and their values

Comment: @Andreas: because it is inside another loop which read each packet, i want to make sure it works correctly.

Comment: @Red Lion - I'll provide some working example code in my answer to your question

Comment: @Andreas: will you consider my main code if I paste it here please?

Answer (score 0):

@Shervin

does it right?

```
package myclassifier;


public class Flows implements Comparable<Flows> {

    String srcAddr, dstAddr, srcPort, dstPort, protocol;

    public Flows(String sIP, String dIP){
        this.srcAddr = sIP;
        this.dstAddr = dIP;
    }

    public int compareTo(Flows other) {
            int res = this.srcAddr.compareTo(other.srcAddr);
            if (res != 0) {
                return res;
            }
            res = this.dstAddr.compareTo(other.dstAddr);
            if (res != 0) {
                return res;
            }
            res = this.srcPort.compareTo(other.srcPort);
            if (res != 0) {
                return res;
            }
            res = this.dstPort.compareTo(other.dstPort);
            if (res != 0) {
                return res;
            }
            return this.protocol.compareTo(other.protocol);
}

     @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((dstAddr == null) ? 0 : dstAddr.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((dstPort == null) ? 0 : dstPort.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((srcAddr == null) ? 0 : srcAddr.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((srcPort == null) ? 0 : srcPort.hashCode());
        return result;

    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;

        Flows other = (Flows) obj;

        if (dstAddr == null) {
            if (other.dstAddr != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dstAddr.equals(other.dstAddr))
            return false;

        if (dstPort == null) {
            if (other.dstPort != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dstPort.equals(other.dstPort))
            return false;

        if (srcAddr == null) {
            if (other.srcAddr != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!srcAddr.equals(other.srcAddr))
            return false;

        if (srcPort == null) {
            if (other.srcPort != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!srcPort.equals(other.srcPort))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, but you should use generics, so that you don't have to manually cast.
The safest thing you can do is ask your editor to generate it for you.
You can also use Lombok (www.projectlombok.org) and annotate your Class, and it will generate that for you.

Comment: i cant add LomBok to my ide because  is not compatible with that. and i can't do it because i customized my netbeans in order to works with jnetpcap library and it wasn't about adding only one library.
i don not know how to use generics.
but thanks anyway.

Comment: Looks perfect. I added "implements Comparable<Flows>" for you, so that compareTo actually can be used.

Comment: Oh but you should ideally not be able to change the state of the class. Otherwise the hashcode changes when the state changes, and therefore won't return what you expect when you do hashmap.get(key).

In other words, make srcAddress and destAddress final.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to use the `flows` and `flowStatics` variables again -

```
HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics> myHashMap = new HashMap<Flows, FlowStatics>();
myHashMap.put(new Flows(sIP,dIP), new FlowStatics(packetLength,timeArrival));
```